# How to pass two or more dataframes from a module to main script

Tags: python, dataframe, module

Edit with @RJ Adriaansen update:
I'm trying to pull two or more dataframes from a module so that I can use the data in the main script.
I only get 4 empty dataframes returned from the df_make module.

The main and df_make codes are below.
Any advice would be great thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import df_make

df_trn = pd.DataFrame()
df_trn_trk = pd.DataFrame()
df_jky = pd.DataFrame()
df_jky_code = pd.DataFrame()

def main():

df_make.jky_trn(df_trn, df_trn_trk, df_jky, df_jky_code)
#df_make.jky_trn([df_trn])

print(df_trn)
print(df_trn_trk)
print(df_jky)
print(df_jky_code)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()



import pandas as pd

#def jky_trn(df_trn):
def jky_trn(df_trn, df_trn_trk, df_jky, df_jky_code):   


#global df_trn
#global df_trn_trk
#global df_jky
#global df_jky_code

path = (r"C:\Users\chris\Documents\UKHR\PythonSand\PY_Scripts\StackOF")
xls_tbl = "\Racecards.xlsx"
xls_link = path + xls_tbl

df1 = pd.read_excel(xls_link, usecols=["Jockey","Course","RaceDesc"])
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls_link, usecols=["Trainer","Course","RaceDesc"])

df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=["Jockey","Course","RaceDesc"])
df1 = df1.dropna()          # Remove rows with NaN

df1['Course'] = df1['Course'].str.replace(' \(AW\)', '')    #Replace (AW) in Course
df2['Course'] = df2['Course'].str.replace(' \(AW\)', '')

df_jky = df1[['Jockey']].copy()
df_jky_code = df1[['Jockey', 'Course']].copy()
df_jky = df_jky.drop_duplicates()
df_jky_code = df_jky_code.drop_duplicates()

df_trn = df2[['Trainer']].copy()
df_trn_trk = df2[['Trainer', 'Course']].copy()
df_trn = df_trn.drop_duplicates()
df_trn_trk = df_trn_trk.drop_duplicates()

#print(df_jky_code)
#print(df_trn_trk)

return df_jky, df_jky_code, df_trn, df_trn_trk
```

Comment: You're passing one argument (1 list), but 4 arguments are required. Try not wrapping the arguments in a list, ie: `df_make.jky_trn(df_trn, df_trn_trk, df_jky, df_jky_code)`

Comment: Thanks RJ - it does something extra - I now get 4 empty dataframes returned to the main script.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that I needed to refer to the dataframes as a tuple item in the main script e.g. `df_jt = df_make.jky_trn()`

The new main script code is:

```
import pandas as pd
```

import df_make

def main():

```
df_jt = df_make.jky_trn()

print(df_jt[0]) 
print(df_jt[1])
print(df_jt[2])
print(df_jt[3])
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()